How can a process in Windows be detected immediately after its creation, before execution begins, to enable interception during initialization?
Injecting a DLL to intercept ShellExecuteExW API calls for detecting hidden cmd.exe executions. However, processes often finish before detection, making injection ineffective. Since ShellExecuteExW is called early, the API call is missed before the injection. How can DLLs be injected at the earliest execution stage to ensure interception, and processes detected instantly to avoid missing execution?
Done DLL injection during runtime, expecting to intercept ShellExecuteExW calls, but processes complete too quickly, missing the API calls.
